# Adding images to text posts with Tumblr API

Tags: tumblr

I'm trying to use the Tumblr API to automatically create a post based on a template in my app.  The template is meant to generate a text post, but includes several embedded images.

However, I can't figure out how to upload these images to Tumblr. The [API documentation](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posting) only lists `type`, `state`, `tags`, `tweet`, `date`, `format`, `slug`, `title`, and `body` as valid parameters for text posts. How can I upload these images? Would the `data` parameter used by photo posts work? Should I use data URLs? (The images aren't particularly small, but maybe Tumblr will convert them for me.) Should I upload them somewhere else and point my `img` tags at those external URLs?

If it matters, I'm doing this in a Mac app, and I intend to use [TMTumblrSDK](https://github.com/tumblr/TMTumblrSDK).

Comment: Use `body` as it relates to the text post type. The content of `body` should content markup generated by your app. Your app would need to handle including img markup inside the text markup, not Tumblr API.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the API documents, it would seem that the parameters for All Post Types can coexist with only one of the other types. So you would have to choose either 'text' or 'photo' as a type.

Because you wish to have a specific format to your post(s), you're going to have to use 'text' for your type. You would then as you thought have to upload the images to a separate location and include them in your html. If you were to submit the files as binary data in a 'photo' type post you would lose the control of formatting and it would be delegated to how your theme is coded to handle galleries...

Although it seems that you are allowed html in the 'caption' element of a photo so you could send one or more images up that way and potentially depending upon your theme include others in the caption.

Answer (score 0):

Tumblr API is bit confusing when it comes to `#Posting`

You have to add 3 Params to Post Image with Text

1. Type
2. Caption
3. Source

See [My Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867481/how-to-post-image-or-text-in-tumblr-android/25073702#25073702) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

We can upload static files for theme template on this form:
http://www.tumblr.com/themes/upload_static_file
Once uploaded, files cannot be deleted or changed.
And we can use HTML codes on page to insert these images.

Comment: This will work, however I believe the service is for theme assets only and maybe considered an abuse of the system.